# Why is “collaborate” not spelled “collabourate” in British English?

Tags: british-english, orthography, o-ou

Everyone knows that *labour* in British English is *labor* in American English.

However, a cursory examination of a dictionary shows the words *collab**ou**rate* and *collab**ou**rator,* derived from the mentioned word *labour,* do not exist in British English.

Why not?

Comment: [This Etymology Online article](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=-or&allowed_in_frame=0) shows that the -or vs -our situation has been in a constant state of flux for centuries.

Comment: Thank you, Edwin! I think the pair vapour — evaporate is the same as mine and is mentioned in the last paragraph in your link. Right?

Comment: Related: [Is “vapourise” considered incorrect, even in British English?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/153392), [Should “glamourous” be considered incorrect?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/67445), [Why is it spelled “curiosity” instead of “curiousity?”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/197173/why-is-it-spelled-curiosity-instead-of-curiousity)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on a false premise and assumption based on no verified or supported fact.

Comment: Apologies for the horribly phrased comment above :) But the question is still off topic for this site.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bearing in mind that orthography is to some degree capricious, nonetheless the reason "why not?" can be affirmed in this case. Simply, 'collaborate' is a much later borrowing than 'labour', and draws its spelling from different etymons. 'Collaborate', in short, is *not* derived from 'labour' per se.

For 'collaborate', the [*OED Online*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/36195?redirectedFrom=collaborate&) gives this etymology,

> < modern French *collaborer*, or its original, Latin *collabōrāre*

and the first attestation of the word's use is from 1871:

> 1871   J. H. Appleton *Life & Lit. Relics* (1881) 25   The collaborators of the Revue critique, especially those who collaborate for the Academy.

For 'labour', however, the [same source](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/104732#eid39838660) gives this etymology:

> Etymology:  Of multiple origins. Partly a borrowing from French. Partly a borrowing from Latin.
>   Etymons: French *labure*; Latin *labor*.
>   < Anglo-Norman *labure*, Anglo-Norman and Old French *labur*, *labor*, Anglo-Norman and Old French, Middle French *labour*, Old French, Middle French *labeur* (French *labeur*) trouble, effort, affliction, misfortune (first half of the 12th cent. in Anglo-Norman), hard work (1155), burden, task (c1170 or earlier in Anglo-Norman), suffering (c1270 or earlier in Anglo-Norman), outcome, product, or result of work (1283), ....

In the case of 'labour', the earliest attested uses in English occurred in the 1300s, much earlier than the appearance of 'collaborate' in the 1800s.

The spelling of 'labour' with 'u', then, is a consequence of its earlier borrowing from etymons with at least one spelling in 'u'; 'collaborate', on the other hand, was borrowed at a much later date and derives from etymons without the spelling in 'u'.